# Add degree sign to a label with different font sizes - Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, nsstring, uilabel, swift5

I am building a weather app. In this app, I am showing the temperature value to the user. In this value, I want to make the temperature  value and degree sign different sizes. Because when the degree sign is the same size as the temperature value it alters the center of the view.

I try the NSAttributedText way like this.

```swift
   let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: temperature.value,
                                                 attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)])

      attrString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string:"°",
                                                  attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)]))
      temperature = attrString
```

I try the Unicode version "\u{00B0}" of the degree sign too. It doesn't matter by the way.

The result was like this.
[image]

However, I want a result like this.
[image]

How can I achive to this look?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add additional attributes `.baselineOffset: NSNumber(value: 18)` where you add "°" in temperature.value:

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: temperature.value,
                                                         attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)])

attrString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string:"°",
                                                    attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18),.baselineOffset: NSNumber(value: 18)]))
temperature = attrString
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make use of the `.baselineOffset` key. Add this to the attributes dictionary for the degree symbol:

```
.baselineOffset: 16
```

Adjust the number to get the exact position you want. The bigger the number the higher up the degree symbol will appear.

You might also want to try playing around with the `.kern` attribute key as well if you want the characters to appear closer together (use a negative value).